# How to find results being between two values of different keys with Redis?

Tags: redis

I'm creating a game matchmaking system using Redis based on MMR, which is a number that pretty much sums up the skill of a player. Therefore the system can match him/her with others who are pretty much with the same skill.
For example if a player with MMR of 1000 joins the queue, system will try to find other ppl with MMR of range 950 to 1050 to match with this player. But if after one minute it cannot find any player with given stats it will scale up the range to 900 to 1100 (a constant threshold).
What I want to do is really easy with relational database design but I can't figure out how to do it with Redis.

The queue table implementation would be like this:

```
+----+---------+------+-------+
| ID | USER_ID | MMR  | TRIES |
+----+---------+------+-------+
|  1 |      50 | 1000 |     1 |
|  2 |      70 | 1500 |     1 |
|  3 |     350 | 1200 |     1 |
+----+---------+------+-------+
```

So when a new player queues up, it will check it's MMR against other players in the queue if it finds one between 5% Threshold it will match the two players if not it will add the new player to the table and wait for new players to queue up to compare or to pass 1 minute and the cronjob increment the tries and retry to match players.

The only way I can imagine is to use two separate keys for the low and high of each player in the queue like this

`MatchMakingQueue:User:1:Low => 900`
`MatchMakingQueue:User:1:High => 1100`

but the keys will be different and I can't get for example all users in between range of low of 900 to high of 1100!

I hope I've been clear enough any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the sorted set? https://redis.io/commands/zadd

Comment: Or you might want to consider using RediSearch

Comment: @GuyKorland The problem with sorted set is I can't scale the MMR for matchmaking. It just saves the MMR as score how can I tell it to increase the range of matchmaking from 800-1200 to 600-1400?

Answer (score 4):

As **@Guy Korland** had suggested, a Sorted Set can be used to track and match players based on their MMR, and I do not agree with the OP's "won't scale" comment.

Basically, when a new player joins, the ID is added to a zset with the MMR as its score.

```
ZADD players:mmr 1000 id:50
```

The matchmaking is made for each user, e.g. id:50 with the following query:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE players:mmrs 1050 950 LIMIT 0 2
```

A match is found if two IDs are returned and at least one of them is different than that of the new player. To make the match, both IDs (the new player's and the matched with one) need to be removed from the set - I'd use a Lua script to implement this piece of logic (matching and removing) for atomicity and communication reduction, but it can be done in the client as well.

There are different ways to keep track of the retries, but perhaps the simplest one is to use another Sorted Set, where the score is that metric.

The following pseudo Redis Lua code is a minimal example of the approach:

```
local kmmrs, kretries = KEYS[1], KEYS[2]
local id = ARGV[1]

local mmr = redis.call('ZSCORE', kmmrs, id)
local retries = redis.call('ZSCORE', kretries, id)
local min, max = mmr*(1-0.05*retries), mmr*(1+0.05*retries)
local candidates = redis.call('ZREVRANGEBYSCORE', kmmrs, max, min, 'LIMIT', 0, 2)

if #candidates < 2 then
  redis.call('ZINCRBY', kretries, 1, id)
  return nil 
end

local reply
if candidates[1] ~= id then
  reply = candidates[1]
else
  reply = candidates[2]
end

redis.call('ZREM', kmmrs, id, reply)
redis.call('ZREM', kretries, id, reply)
return reply
```

Comment: What's a best practice to deal with data races here ? You are doing multiple operations, and by the time when you do ZREM, another process could already ZREM-ed your candidate. The result is that one player is matched into two games at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get the problem right! Your problem is that you want to find all the users in a given range of MMR value. What if You make other users say that "I'm falling in this range".

Read about Redis Pub/Sub.

1. When a user joins in, publish its MMR to rest of the players.
2. Write the code on the user side to check if his/her MMR is falling in the range.
3. If it is, user will publish back to a channel that it is falling in that range. Else, user will silently discard the message.
4. repeat these steps if you get no response back in 1 minute.

You can make one channel (let's say MatchMMR) for all users to publish MMR for match request which should be suscribed by all the users. And make user specific channel in case somebody has a MMR in the calculated range.

Form you published messages such that you can send all the information like "retry count", "match range percentage", "MMR value" etc. so that your code at user side can calculate if it is the right fit for the MMR.

Read mode about redis Pub/Sub at: https://redis.io/topics/pubsub